# Ciphers Program modelling - Inheritence and other OOP concepts

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, encryption

Ok so I have tried implementing simple mono alphabetic substitution ciphers like Caesars , digraph like playfair , polyalphabetic ones  like autokey, vigenre and a few others in c++ {without using classes}. Now i would like to bring together all these ciphers and a few others and package it into a single project.I have started coding a few lines, but i'm not sure how i must design it. Here's how my classes look.

my front end 
    //main.cpp contains few switch cases to chose the right cipher for encryption.

```
//cipher.cpp implements class cipher.In a crude format the class looks like
class cipher
{
protected:
string plaintxt,ciphertxt;
public:
virtual bool encrypt()=0;
virtual bool decrypt()=0;
virtual bool tabulate()=0;
}
```

this class is interfaced by cipher.h

```
//mono_alphabetic.cpp implemants the class mono_alpha

class mono_alpha : public cipher
{
 protected:
 map<string,string> Etable,Dtable;
 public:
 bool Encrypt();
bool Decrypt();
}
```

Now i'm using a simple example of atbash cipher here.For those of you who don't know what an atbash cipher is, it is a mode of encryption in which each character in a given string is encrypted with its equivalent character as per position in the reverse alphabetic order. For eg. A ->Z   Z->A   B->Y  M->N  so on.

```
class atbash : public mono_alpha
{
  public:
  bool tabulate();  // makes a hash map were A is mapped to Z M to N e.t.c
atbash(string&);  // accepts a string and copies it to string plaintxt.

}
```

This is a very crude example. Only the class design is presented here.Here are a few doubts of mine.

implemantation : I would accepts a string from the user and then pass it to the constructor of class atbash, where it is copied to the string data member plaintxt inherited from the base class cipher. Then i would invoke the function tabulate from the constructor.Now i have two choices either tabulate() generates a hash map of encryption table and store it in Etable, or it could also generate the decryption table.In the case of an atbash cipher these are one but the same. But what about the case of a general mono alphabetic substitution cipher ? how would i force the tabulate functio to create either one.

my idea was to pass a character argument to the constructor to the constructor which describes if the given string is to be encrypted or decrypted and accordingly saves it in either one among plaintxt or ciphertxt.Further the constructor passes this character argument to tabulate function which tabulates the encryption or decryption table accordingly.Is this good ?

any suggestion on how to improve this ?

interface : my way of implementing an interface to all these ciphers from main.cpp was to use swith case like.

```
switch(chosen_value)
{
case 1: cout<<"atbash encryption";
cipher*ptr = new atbash ("a string");

// ptr->tabulate();   if it isn't being called directly from the constructor.(here it is)

case 2:
cout<< "caeser's cipher";

.....................
.

.....
}
```

Are there any better ways to implement this without using switch case.

also as you can see i have used a base class pointer to an object of the derived class for doing this.I know it isn't necessary here and the I can simply proceed  by declaring an object. Is there any real importance to referencing objects through a base class pointer ?
I have heard that these base class pointers can be a real life savior sometimes ! If so please direct me on scenarios where this simplifies coding . Is declaring pure virtual functions in the base class not of any use in this particular case.Is it just bloating the code here ?

should i go on with separating the class implementations into separate files like i have done here or should i just cramp up all these code in a single main.cpp which would make inheritance a lot easier as you don't have to use header files.

Please guide me on this.I have zero professional experience in coding and would love to here your opinions.

Comment: Do you only use monoalphabetic substitution ciphers? If not, does `tabulate()` really always make sense? Do you only use ciphers which can encrypt inplace / use the same space for input and output? Do you actually want to do it inplace (as an option / mandatory)? Shall your library be useable / extendable from C / C compatible languages? Do you want to support multiple engines for encrypting / decrypting according to the same cipher?

Comment: Shall your framework be multithread safe? Maybe only after registering all transcoders?

Comment: You still interested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas, in no particular order

- Have different classes for encryption and for decryption. That will solve your doubt on what to use. So the cipher base class becomes a base class for a transformation of a string into other. (not an expert on patterns, but I believe this is the [Command Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15207/Design-Patterns-Command-Pattern))
- The nice thing about having an object to represent the algorithm is that it can have state. You might want to add a reset() method to be able to reuse the object on a new execution if the creation of the object is expensive.
- You can make the base class a function object with an abstract operator(). This operator() gets implemented in each specific encryption and descryption classes. Using this allows you to handle this classes as functions (the downside is that it is perhaps less clear what you're doing).
- It is correct to handle everything through pointers to the base class (or references or smart pointers)
- In order to create the right type of operation, have a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) class (this is again a pattern). This can be a class with a creator method where you indicate the algorithm and the encryption/decryption direction. The Factory returns a pointer to the base class, pointing the appropriate implementation.
- The implementation can be a vector or a map or an array of some specific factory objects (whose job is to instantiate an algorithm object of the different types)... Alternative you can have a static method on each derived class and store a pointer to method in the structure.
- The structure (vector/map/array/whatever) is used for fast selection of the right algorithm. If the number of algorighms is small, the use of a switch statement is probably fine. The structure is contained in the Factory class and initialize on its constructor.
- You must mind the lifecycle of the objects created. Objects are created by the Factory, but who should destroy them?
- Consider what you're going to use to represent the encrypted/decrypted messages and wether they become non-printable or they can become too large.

There are many design decisions here, many trade offs that depends on different things.

Hope the above lines give you some ideas to start.

---

### Edit: adding a more concrete example

We will start with an `Operation` class. This assumes that we can have both encrypters and decrypters can be called with the same API

```
class Operation {
public:
    virtual ~Operation() { }
    virtual std::string operator()(const std::string &input)=0;

    virtual void reset() { }
};
```

Notes on this:

- Assumes that the API is string input gives a string output. This is the `operator()` pure virtual method.
- Added a virtual destructor. We're going to be dealing mostly with references to Operation. However implementations of the algorithm my need to destroy their own things, so the destructor must be virtual so that when deleting an Operation pointer it will also invoke the destructor of the derived class.
- Added a `reset()` method. This has a default implementation that does nothing. Potentially derived classes might store state, this method is intended to return the operation to its initial step so that you don't have to scrap it and create another.

Now some of the derived classes:

```
class MyEncoder: public Operation {
public:
    static Operation *create() {
        return new MyEncoder();
    }
    std::string operator()(const std::string &input) {
        // Do things.
        return std::string();
    }
};

class MyDecoder: public Operation {  ...  };

class OtherEncoder: public Operation { ... };

class OtherDecoder: public Operation { ... };
```

I'm only showing in full `MyEncoder` We see a static method `create` that we will talk about later.
The implementation of the algorithm happens on the implementation of the `operator()`
You could:

- Keep state in attributes of MyEncoder
- Initialize stuff on constructor
- ... and perhaps destroy things in a destructor.
- Potentially include an implementation of the reset() method to reuse the object in another invocation.

Now for the Factory:

```
class OperationFactory {
public:
    enum OperationDirection {
        OD_DECODER=0,
        OD_ENCODER
    };

    enum OperationType {
        OT_MY=0,
        OT_OTHER
    };
    ....
};
```

Just declared the class and a couple of enumerations to help us distinguish between encoders and decoders and the two algorithm I'm going to use.

We need some place to store things, so the Factory class ends with:

```
class OperationFactory {
public:
...
private:
    typedef Operation *(*Creator)();
    typedef std::map<OperationType,Creator> OperationMap;

    OperationMap mEncoders;
    OperationMap mDecoders;
};
```

Here:

- The first typedef gives a name to a function pointer. This is a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to an `Operation`. A static method is the same as a function (at least regarding function pointers)... so this typedef allows us to give a name to the mysterious `create()` static method we had above.
- The second typedef is just shortcut for the lengthy std::map definition. This is a map from `OperatonType` to `Creator` function.
- We define two of those maps, one for Encoder, one for Decoders. You could devise a different way.

With that we can provide some methods for the user to obtain what it wants:

```
class OperationFactory {
public:
...

    Operation *getOperation(OperationDirection _direction,OperationType _type) const {
        switch(_direction) {
        case OD_DECODER:
            return getDecoder(_type);
        case OD_ENCODER:
            return getEncoder(_type);
        default:
            // Or perhaps throw an exception
            return 0;
        }
    }

    Operation *getEncoder(OperationType _type) const {
        OperationMap::const_iterator it=mEncoders.find(_type);
        if(it!=mEncoders.end()) {
            Creator creator=it->second;
            return (*creator)();
        } else {
            // Or perhaps throw an exception
            return 0;
        }
    }

    Operation *getDecoder(OperationType _type) const {
 .... // similar but over the mDecoders
    }
....
};
```

So, we look up the OperationType in the map and get a pointer to a function (`Creator`) type, we can call this function `(*creator)()` to obtain the instance of the `Operation` that we requested.

Some words on `(*creator)()`:

- `creator` is of type `Creator`... so it is a pointer to a function.
- `(*creator)` is the function (the same as if `p` is an `int *`, `*p` is of type int)...
- `(*creator)()` is the invocation of a function.

To complete this we need to really have something in the map... so we add that on the constructor:

```
class OperationFactory {
public:
....    
    OperationFactory() {
        mEncoders[OT_MY]=&MyEncoder::create;
        mEncoders[OT_MY]=&MyDecoder::create;
        mEncoders[OT_OTHER]=&OtherEncoder::create;
        mEncoders[OT_OTHER]=&OtherDecoder::create;
    }
....
};
```

We insert for each algorithm the pointer to their `create` static methods.

Finally how do we use it?

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    OperationFactory f;

    Operation *o=f.getOperation(OperationFactory::OD_DECODER,OperationFactory::OT_MY);
    std::string toTransform="Hello world";
    std::string transformed=(*o)(toTransform);

    delete o; // don't forget to delete it.

}
```

Here we have an instance of the `OperationFactory` `f` from where we can request the creation of our desired operation with the `getOperation()` methods.

The object that we got can be used to execute the algorithm. Note that `(*o)(toTransform)` is formaly similar to our invocation of creator above, but there are differences:

- `o` is a pointer to an object of type `Operation` (actually is really a pointer `MyEncoder`)
- `(*o) is an object of type`Operation`(well, really of type`MyEnconder`)
- `(*o)(toTransform)` is the invocation of the `operator()` method of the `MyEncoder` type.

We could have used this technique on the Creator: using an object-function instead of a pointer to function... but it would have been more code.

Note that the factory allocates memory... and this memory must be disposed when no longer needed. Ways of not doing this are to use unique_ptr or shared_ptr...

Note that `getOperation()` could return a null pointer when it cannot find the algorithm requested... so the calling code should check for that possibility.

Alternatively the implementation of `getOperation()` could have chosen to throw an exception when the algorithm is not found... again the calling code should then have had a try/catch.

---

Now, how to add a new algorithm:

1. Derive and implement your encoder and decoder classes from Operation
2. Expand the enum OperationType
3. register the creators in the OperationFactory constructor.
4. ... use it.

Comment: Your answer seems great, but I'm afraid that I m new to few implementations you have suggested above. Like **class becomes a function object**.       **some sample code for designing the factory class would be great**

Comment: @krish Edited the response to add more details.